# How to handle begin of tap in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

I have a ScrollView displaying elements.
I would like to detect when the use starts pressing an element to reduce his dimension until he releases the finger or start dragging (like in Today section of AppStore).

I tried to use LongPressGesture.onChanged but when I use .gesture(Something) the ScrollView scrolling doesn't work anymore.

In UIKit I would have used the TouchDown Event.
There is a solution?

This is my code:

```
@State touchDownIndex: Int?

var body: some View {

    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(items) {item in
                    ItemView(item: item).scaleEffect(self.items.firstIndex(of: item)! == self.touchDownIndex ? 1 : 0.9)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you passing the value of `item` to the `.scaleEffect`?

Comment: did you try to set the property cancelsTouchesInView = false for the gestureRecognizer?

Comment: @Andrew I was wrong to position the modifier

Comment: @Chris This is SwiftUI not UIKit. Gesture, unlike UIGestureRecognizer, doesn't have this property.

Comment: Did you come up with any solution @LorenzoFiamingo? I think Introspection package would help but I am on watchOS SwiftUI and that is not supported.